# Lowercase RegEx URL

Tags: regex

Can someone write a RegEx that can match :

- only lowercase URLs that can have `a-z` letters,
- `0-9` numbers and `-`,
- `http://` (https is not required),
- `www.`
- and *doesn't* have `default.aspx`?

This is a URL that RegEx must match:

`http://www.somedomain.net/news/148/some-text-to-act-as-news-title.aspx`

or

`http://subdomain.somedomain.net/news/148/some-text-to-act-as-news-title.aspx` (withour `www.`).

This is my attempt: `[a-z0-9]{1,}-*`. Only matches single words, words with `-` and numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with look-ahead assertion:

```
^http://[a-z0-9-.]+(?:(?!/default\.aspx)/[a-z0-9-.]+)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^http://((?!default\.aspx)[a-z0-9\-\./])*$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^http://[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z0-9]+(/(?!.*default\.aspx)[a-z0-9./-]+)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

you should exclude the urls that have Uppercase and default.aspx with your native lang.  but if you want everything BUT the caps do this.

```
[a-z/- 0-9]*
```

Comment: the general rule for regex is if you have a search function in the native language that can do something easily it usually faster than regex.  if you just want to say, "skip this line if it has an UC char", that will most likely be faster in the NL.